# How to hide the hourglass icon in C# (.NET Compact Framework)

Tags: c#, compact-framework, cursor

does anyone have an idea how to hide the hourglass icon when you execute an application from another?

E.g. App-A with pretty background screen starts App-B. While App-B is loading windows puts this ugly grey block with the rotating hourglass in the middle of App-A.

I have tried calling System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Hide(); but that did not seem to deter windows. It is possible that I did not use it correctly. Any ideas most welcome.

TIA (Thanks in Advance),
Ends

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact you're calling it an "hourglass" indicates to me that this is not a Windows Mobile device but instead a generic CE device.  Unfortunately the CF loader tells the OS to display the hourglass when it starts up and there is actually no way to prevent that from a CF perspective.  You can remove the hourglass cursor altogether in the OS itself if you control the OS, but you can't prevent the CF from showing it if it's there.

Comment: It would seem that ctacke is correct. It does not help to set the Cursor as the application does not have control while the process is being started. It makes sense that this is BSP (Board support package) level behaviour. You are correct that this is a CE device.

Comment: How do you remove this from the image?

Comment: remove SYSGEN_CURSOR and rebuild the OS.  This has to be done with Platform builder and is only an option if you're the OS creator.  The fact you asked the question indicates that you actually aren't, so it's unlikely you'll be able to do it.

Comment: I am the OS creator.  I did remove that to get rid of the mouse cursor. That isn't the hourglass that is showing up.  I put a screenshot of the hourglass in my "answer". I think that is what the original question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the `Cursor.Current` property to Cursors to `Cursors.Default`?

Here you can find the [documentation for this property on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.current.aspx) and for the [Cursor class here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling Cursor.Hide before App A starts App B and then unhiding it after the window finishes loading?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

http://www.cprogramdevelop.com/1695088/